# GetRectangle для BitmapFactory?

Tags: java, android

Как получить Rectangle для BitmapFactory.Что-то типо такого a.getRectangle, где а BitmapFactory. В итоге нужно, чтобы заработало в данной строчке кода

if(Rect.intersects(a.getRectangle(),b.getRectangle()))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `BitmapFactory` позволяет получить изображение из файла или потока.
2. Следовательно, нужно полученное изображение поместить в некий контейнер, через который можно будет получить нужные данные о прямоугольнике, в который это изображение впишется.
3. `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);`
4. С полученным экземпляром Bitmap (назовём его bitmap) можно уже что-то делать.
5. `bitmap.getHeight`, `bitmap.getWidth` - высота и ширина битмапа.
6. Можно построить экземпляр Rect на основе этих параметров. `(Rect(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)`, где `left` = 0, `top` = 0, `right` = `bitmap.getWidth`, `bottom = bitmap.getHeight`)
7. Следовательно, просто делаем метод, который принимает на вход Bitmap а на выход выдаёт `Rectangle (Rect getBitmapRectangle(Bitmap bitmap))`.
8. Применим:    `if(Rect.intersects(getBitmapRectangle(a.decodeStream(inputStream1)),getBitmapRectangle(b.decodeStream(inputStream2)))...`

Comment: а почему он ругается на inputStream?

Comment: inputStream1 и inputStream2 скорее всего не определены в Вашем приложении.
Обычно, экземпляры InputStream создаются примерно так:
InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("cat.png");
В Вашем случае, я полагаю, нужно передать фабрике открытый таким образом поток.